# Android Studio data from nfc tag to list

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nfc

I would like it to add the tag to the list every time it scans. Then display it in the TextView in Activity

I tried copying the array and increasing its size but to no avail
`

```
override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
    val test = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test)
    val mNdef = Ndef.get(tag)
    val test123 = mutableListOf<String>()

    //val myList = mutableListOf("")

    if (mNdef != null) {
        val mNdefMessage = mNdef.cachedNdefMessage
        val firstRecord = mNdefMessage.records[0]
        val payload= firstRecord.payload
        val textArray= payload.copyOfRange(payload[0].toInt() + 1, payload.size)

        var text = String(textArray)

        test123.add(text)
        Log.i("TAG", test123.toString())

        test.text = text

    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a scope issue.

As you define `val test123 = mutableListOf<String>()` in the scope of `onTagDiscovered` then it won't be available outside of `onTagDiscovered` and will be reset every time a Tag is scanned.

You probably want to define the list in the `Activity` scope, but be careful `onTagDiscovered` is run in a separate thread to the main UI thread, so trying to use `findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test)` will cause an error.

You will need to use [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) update the TextView